# при подключении owl carousel 2 ничего не отображается

Tags: owl-carousel

подключаю локально карусель, но не отображается совсем ничего.
HTML,к которому подключается карусель я получаю из js файла, но если html написать напрямую, то есть не из js файла, то все работает, подскажите как решить проблему

голова:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?=$title?></title>
    <link rel="icon" href="logo.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme/bootstrap 3/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme/css/main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fontawesome/all.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider/css/owl.carousel.css">
```

низ:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="pages/productPage/js/slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="theme/bootstrap 3/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="pages/productPage/js/product.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="slider/js/owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: тоже самое, причём я сделал всё то, что посоветовал человек выше

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="common">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
})
</script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
```

```html
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
</div>
```